# Run queries in parallel

Tags: mysql, linux, multi-thread

I am running a sql script on mysql 5.7.18 ubuntu server 16.04 that does a large number of updates in one table. Each one of the 50k updates takes under a second but the total run time is very long (>20m).

I can see from PROCESSLIST that only one thread is running and is processing the updates one-by-one.

How can I use multiple threads to speed the execution ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you wrote "each one of the..." it sounds like you are updating individual rows. Rather than doing a row at a time, have you explored writing the SQL so you are letting the DB update many rows in one SQL statement? That will likely get you much better performance than trying to multi-thread manually.

Comment: You are correct. Unfortunately we cannot edit the query at this point. Can we at least make it run more parallel ?

Comment: Split your set of data to update into n equally sized sets and launch n copies of your update script that connect independently to the DB. This may be faster or slower depending on where your DB server's bottlenecks are. You can see them doing something like this with bash on Percona (MySQL fork) here: https://www.percona.com/blog/2014/01/07/increasing-slow-query-performance-with-parallel-query-execution/

Answer (score 1):

From the book, High Performance MySQL - 2nd Edition - 2008:

> MySQL can’t execute a single query in parallel on many CPUs. This is a feature offered by some other database servers, but not MySQL. We mention it so that you won’t spend a lot of time trying to figure out how to get parallel query execution on MySQL!
>
> https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/high-performance-mysql/9780596101718/ch04.html

From the Percona blog - 23 Jan 2019

> Finally: MySQL 8.0.14 has (for now limited) an ability to perform parallel query execution. At the time of writing it is limited to `select count(*) from table` queries as well as check table queries.
>
> https://www.percona.com/blog/2019/01/23/mysql-8-0-14-a-road-to-parallel-query-execution-is-wide-open/

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve some mysql parallelism with xargs:

`cat <./file.sql> | xargs -n <num of cores> -d '\n' -I {} mysql -e {}`

The xargs -d '\n' statment make only \n be the delimiter (usefull if each line o .sql file has spaces)

-n  Limits the number of arguments per command line generated by xargs. Without -n 1 and using -P 0, chances are that only one exec will be done sometimes.

-P  Limits the number of xargs generated processes at a time (the default is 1). -P 0 (P zero) is the same of -P ($nproc).

But, despite of more than one instance o mysql run in parallel (in separate subshells), the performance don´t achieve 2x. Maybe some DB lock issue.

Answer (score 0):

Few suggestions:

Make sure you have defined proper index. To define them, read the beautiful answer posted by Gordon Linoff [here a SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30645283/sql-update-query-taking-too-long)

Secondly, Refer [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1627794/mysql-update-takingtoo-long-time). It tells you about optimization tricks like

```
show create table table1;
explain select * from table1
```

and

```
OPTIMIZE TABLE table1;
```

Basically, both the answers talk about index.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that MySQL natively supports any kind of multi-threading. There is  concept called sharding that may help you. This requires that you install a plugin for running.

more information and a Shard tool can be found here: https://www.percona.com/blog/2014/01/07/increasing-slow-query-performance-with-parallel-query-execution/

EDIT: You have already made a comment that you can't change your query. I'm afraid that you may be stuck in a single threaded world. I think that Oracle does this on purpose to get you interested in their software and ready to upgrade.

Comment: True. I think that MariaDB has a similar plugin for free but I was looking for a quick and dirty solution. Splitting into multiple queries is the way. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You can get some benefit (in InnoDB) with `innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 2`.

You can avoid a lot of overhead if you first insert into a "staging" table, *then* copy into the 'real' table.  [*This*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/staging_table) discusses such.

I hope that your 50K is just a burst.  If you have that continually, your disk will quickly fill up.